# Delete a referenced object in a ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models
from relatedModel.models import RelatedModel

class Model(models.Model)
    relatedObjects = models.ManyToManyField(RelatedModel)
```

Above is a one of my models that references another model. I want to be able to delete specified `relatedObjects` from `Model` without deleting them from `RelatedModel`

I have a `delete` function in the `Model`'s `views.py` that does:

`relatedObject = get_object_or_404(RelatedModel, pk=pk).delete()`

Which is wrong since it deletes the object from the `RelatedModel`'s table.

How can I delete a `RelatedModel` object **only** from the `relatedObjects` field in `Model`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to understand that `relatedObjects` is not actually a part of your `Model` table. When you declare a `ManyToManyField` on a model, Django creates an entirely new table to hold the relationship between the two models, and for your convenience creates a way for them to access each other (e.g. the `relatedObjects` attribute).

If I understand you correctly, you're saying that you don't want to delete either object, you just want to remove the relationship between them. In that case, use the `remove()` method on the [related manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/):

```
model_instance.relatedObjects.remove(relatedmodel_instance)
```

Comment: Wow makes sense even semantically, as I was in the shell adding objects to the `relatedObjects` field with the `add` method while debugging. Not sure why this didn't come to me but thanks, accepted as answer!